# Apple Script cannot work with existing path

Tags: applescript

I have to make an export from a banking app and I like to move the generated file, which is located somewhere deep inside of /tmp/..., to a folder inside documents.

```
tell application "MoneyMoney"
    set exportFile to export transactions from account "DE91787695590008764648" from date "2022-01-01" to date "2022-12-31" as "csv"
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set fileName to name of (POSIX file exportFile as alias)
    set targetName to "/Users/username/Documents/Klientendaten/AccountImport/" & fileName
    move exportFile as POSIX file to folder targetName as POSIX file
end tell

return targetName
```

The script editor tells something with Error in AppleEvent-Routine number -10000. I think it has something to do with targetName, which apple script can't find, but that definitively exists. Is there a mistake in `targetName`? Or is the move-call wrong?

Comment: btw: script has full disk access.

Comment: What type of value does `exportFile` get assigned by the "MoneyMoney" app?

Comment: It's a string containing the path to the exported file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely where you've defined `targetName`: if this is a path to a file (and not a folder), asserting it later to be a `folder` in the **`move`** command will not be possible; if it is a path to a folder, then it almost certainly doesn't exist as it's derived from the name of the file that is exported moments before.

Here's an amended version of the salient portion of your script:

```
set targetPath to "/Users/username/Documents/Klientendaten/AccountImport/"
        
tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to tell (move ¬
        (the exportFile as POSIX file) to the folder ¬
        (targetPath as POSIX file)) as text to return ¬
        the POSIX path
```

I've added in parentheses to aid clarity, although the way you formulated it—even without parentheses—is fine and would work just as well.  This moves the `exportFile` to the folder `AccountImport`.  If you actually wanted to move it to a folder with the same name as the `exportFile`, then this folder needs to be created first:

```
set targetPath to "/Users/username/Documents/Klientendaten/AccountImport/"

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" 
         set exportFile to the file named (exportFile as POSIX file)
         set targetFolder to the folder named (targetPath as POSIX file)
         set targetFolder to make new folder in the targetFolder ¬
                 with properties {name:exportFile's name as text}
         move the exportFile to the targetFolder
         return the POSIX path of (the result as text)
end tell
```